# DNS redirection of a sub domain

Tags: url, redirect, dns, subdomain

i have 2 website :

*site1.com (IP: 1.1.1.1)* and *site2.com (IP: 2.2.2.2)* (not on the same server and hoster)

I would like to have a subdomain on site1.com *(sub)* who redirect to site2.com :
*sub.site1.com redirect to site2.com*

The redirection must be invisible to the user.
When on sub.site1.com, url display is sub.site1.com and note site2.com.

To be more precise:

On the site1.com, i do:

*sub.site1.com CNAME site2.com*

*site2.com CNAME machine.host.com*

*machine.host.com A 2.2.2.2*

It works but i have the generic page of machine.host.com.fr when i call *sub.site1.com*.

*2.2.2.2 (machine.host.com)* is a web server who have multiple site on it.
How to be more specific and redirect sub.site1.com to my site ?

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: I added some details. Redirection is not fully complete. The server is good but my website is not linked.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correclty you need a DNS alias to make the job.

Suppose you have two domains :

site1.com (A) 1.1.1.1
site2.com (A) 2.2.2.2

If you want a new site1.com subdomain pointing site2.com, you need to make a CNAME (alias) register to point site2.com

sub.site1.com (CNAME) site2.com

A possible solution if you want to load another site content (without change the main domain), is load the remote content with an Iframe. With this, you can load remote content invisible to the user.

Comment: Iframe is the solution actually used and i want to suppress that and use dns redirection.